# Python file closes itself

Tags: python, file, io

Whenever I run the snippet here, it will print "False" before immediately following on the line after with "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" Is there anything with rstrip that will close the file?

```
with open(ffile, 'rb') as f:
    print f.closed
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines = (line for line in lines if line)
```

This is the entire snippet

```
ffile = sys.argv[1]
ifile = sys.argv[2]
sha1 = hashlib.sha1()

with open(ifile, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(5000)
        if not data:
            break
        sha1.update(data)
digest = sha1.hexdigest()
digest_int = int(digest, 16)

with open(ffile, 'rb') as f:
    print f.closed
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines = (line for line in lines if line) 


maxid = 0
for l in lines:
    node_name = l.split(' ')[0]
    nextid = l.split(' ')[1]
    nextid = int(nextid, 16)
    if (nextid == digest_int):
        maxid = nextid
        break
    elif nextid < digest_int and not("Finger" in node_name):
        if nextid > maxid:
            maxid = nextid

print str(digest_int)
print str(maxid)
```

There is literally no code that closes anything.

Comment: There's nothing about `rstrip` that will close the file. `rstrip` doesn't even _see_ the file, just each line you read from it. Plus, it doesn't get called until after you `print f.closed`, so it would be too late for it to do anything.

Comment: But then something would have closed the file since on the previous line it is open. Unless False for f.closed actually means it is closed.

Comment: The code you have works fine.  What's the next line of code?  The problem probably occurs there.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. An [mcve] means we can copy the code, paste it into an editor, change the filename to a file we have present, and run the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: "There is literally no code that closes anything" is not true: `with` closes the file. That's the whole point of using `with` statements on files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in this code, but in some other code farther down that you haven't shown us.

What you've written is creating a generator that, when iterated, will yield stripped, non-empty lines out of the file.

That's perfectly fine. But if you don't *use* that generator until after you've closed the file, it will try to get those lines out of a closed file. (Remember, the whole point of generators is that they're *lazy*—they do all the work as late as possible, using as little memory as possible.)

From your comments, it seems like you don't think you're closing the file anywhere. But in fact you are. The whole point of using `with` statements on files is that they close the file as soon as you exit the `with` body.

---

For example, if you do this:

```
with open(ffile, 'rb') as f:
    print f.closed
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines = (line for line in lines if line)

for line in lines:
    print line
```

… that's an error, probably exactly the same kind of error you're seeing.

---

But this:

```
with open(ffile, 'rb') as f:
    print f.closed
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines = (line for line in lines if line)

    for line in lines:
        print line
```

… is just fine. You're using `lines` inside the `with` statement, while the file is still open.

---

And this:

```
with open(ffile, 'rb') as f:
    print f.closed
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    lines = (line for line in lines if line)
    lines = list(line)

for line in lines:
    print line
```

… is also fine. You're using the generator inside the `with` statement, and storing everything in a list, which of course is still around and taking up memory even after the file goes away.

---

What you want to do is probably some variation on the first fix if possible, some variation on the second otherwise. But without seeing any of your code, there's no way of telling you anything more specific.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that I am trying to run a generator.